# Convert to JSONArray angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I've got a json like this:

```
"values": [
    {"name": "name1"},
    {"name": "name2"},
    {"name": "name3"}
]
```

and but now i need convert it into this:

```
values: ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
```

In angularjs (or some function in javascript). Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a simple `map` function:

`json.values = json.values.map(function(valObj){ return valObj.name; });`

(Obviously, for readability, you may want to rename `valObj` to something more descriptive of your Objects)